# wpengine, wordpress multi-site not showing post content when used as varnish backend

Tags: php, wordpress, varnish

In order to achieve the magic of http://someserver.com/blog/ pointing to  myserver.wpengine.com/blog/ I had to create a multisite in wpengine.

From there I was able to point to the backend successfully with a basic varnish rewrite.

So, now the page shows up at someserver-dot-com/blog/ and appears to write post links to someserver-dot-com/blog/some-post when I set 'home' to 'http:/someserver-dot-com/blog'.

But, when I navigate to those posts, I get an internal WP "page not found".  It's not actually a 404, because if I go to http://someserver.com/blog/some-post it returns the page properly, which means the multi-site and references are working properly.  WTF!?!

I've checked the database, and everything appears to be proper in the DB tables.

To me, this is something inside some wordpress php function, cache or something within wpengine.  I've definitely purged the cache of all the things from the network login in the wordpress admin plugin for wpengine. Has anyone experienced this problem?

It's been a few days of debugging, and I've read every man page in existence, and tried setting paths via wp-config, and all that does is increase complexity of writes, and it doesn't seem like it works either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Astonishingly,

This works:

In functions.php, right after php tags, add this line:

update_option('home','http://someblog.com/blog/');

Obviously, this should just add that to the 'home' keypair in the wp_2_options table, but actually it does something else.  It fires this at some point:

```
   $notoptions = wp_cache_get( 'notoptions', 'options' );
      if ( is_array( $notoptions ) && isset( $notoptions[$option] ) ) {
           unset( $notoptions[$option] );                    
           wp_cache_set( 'notoptions', $notoptions, 'options' );
    }
```

I believe this deletes option cache, and currently either wordpress or wpengine has an issue with some cache, and the plain vanilla 'home' keypair should have worked right in the first place, leaving 'site' as 'someblog.wpengine.com' and leaving all wp_config as the plain vanilla multi-site/root configs that wpengine will set-up.